# django admin shows all apps, models, but admin model pages return 404

Tags: django, django-admin

These urls work:

```
/admin
/admin/appname
```

But this does not work for *any* model, including users, groups, or sites:

```
/admin/appname/modelname
```

For example, `/admin/auth` works and shows the `Groups`, and `Users` models, but if I click on either model, navigating to `admin/auth/user`, I receive a 404 not found error.

I first assumed that it was probably a problem in `urls.py` so I commented out everything out besides the admin. It made no difference. Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # main admin
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
admin.autodiscover()
```

Here's my installed apps, in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
)
```

I have of course already tried shutting down the server, running `syncdb`, (as well as running south migrations for apps that were using south), and using `runserver` again. It makes no difference.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling django (same version, 1.3).

> Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. `^admin/ ^$ [name='index']`
> 2. `^admin/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']`
> 3. `^admin/ ^password_change/$ [name='password_change']`
> 4. `^admin/ ^password_change/done/$ [name='password_change_done']`
> 5. `^admin/ ^jsi18n/$ [name='jsi18n']`
> 6. `^admin/ ^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$`
> 7. `^admin/ ^(?P<app_label>\w+)/$ [name='app_list']`
>
> The current URL, `admin/auth/user/`, didn't match any of these.

Comment: What happens if you move `admin.autodiscover()` to the top of the urls.py file, just after the imports?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: um .. that worked, thank you! but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you apparently need to have the `admin.autodiscover()` line *before* the place where you include it in the `urlpatterns` tuple.

This seems to be because the code that calculates the urls for each app/model - `admin.sites.AdminSite.get_urls` - depends on the models already being registered for the admin before it runs. If not, the relevant URLs are not created.